# Setting up a wifi dongle

Tags: pi-2, wifi

I have a raspberry pi 2 running raspbian, and bought a [wifi dongle](https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-wifi.html) to use with it. I can't seem to get it connect to the internet. I have tried following the guide given by the seller, but it was written for Headed units, and I want to go headless. I also tried using sudo raspi-config to set up the internet.

output of [`ifconfig`](https://pastebin.com/TajivfyK)

output of [`lsusb`](https://pastebin.com/JeJvB8fF)

Version: Linux raspberry 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: `and i can seem to get it to work` My first reaction: so what's the problem? But it's probably a typo... Can you tell us what you tried already and what exactly doesn't seem to work? Also add the the version of your OS and the output of `lsusb` and `ifconfig` toyour question?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Please don't use pastebin, instead insert the output direct to the question. You are connected with two interfaces to your local network, one with wired ethernet, one with wifi. Where does the interface `tun0` come from? Do you have a VPN client running? Which of these three interfaces is used to connect to the internet? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: What's security does your network use? Can you see the SSID with an ```iwlist scan``` command? What's in your /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file? Have you set the country code in there?

Comment: so you changed it from "I can seem to get it to work" - which implies it works - to "I can seem to get it to connect to the internet"  - which also implies that it's working ... the opposite of can is can't - do you mean you can't make it work despite that fact that the wifi dongle is clearly working with a valid IP address ?

Comment: Ok i see the issue now. I am using my router as my DNS and i assigning ip based on mac address. I did not realize that it would use the mac of the Dongle. I never test if the internet worked as i can only connect to it through ssh for the time being. Thanks for all your help guys :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that seems to be wrong is what Wifi dongle you are using. I suggest purchasing the following:
https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Edimax-EW-7811Un-WiFi-N150-USB-Adapter-for-Linux-MacOS-Windows-Raspberry-Pi/172798424298?hash=item283b96b4ea:g:KowAAOSwjS9ZfDpM:rk:1:pf:0
If your dongle is not driverless, you can't use it.
Also, after connecting first try to use the GUI to connect to the internet. The GUI wifi button is in the top right hand corner. If that doesn't work, get your Wifi config app onto your desktop to use it. That allows for you to easily connect to the internet.
If all that doesn't work, I point you to the following post:
[How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address)

This goes in detail in how to connect to the internet. If you could also update what are the results for the inputs **sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf** and **lsusb** and **ifconfig** that would make the question clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I had that and a few issues other issues but this helped. My dongle dose not need drivers btw.